# How to retrieve values from mysql database in android studio with java or php using RETROFIT library?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am trying to fetch values from database in android studio textview php for db connection.I'm using Retrofit library. Below is the code I've written to GET the values ... I'm getting this error
"Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $"

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView nametxt, agetxt, phonetxt, emailtxt;
Button retrieveBtn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    nametxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nametxt);
    agetxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.agetxt);
    phonetxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phonetxt);
    emailtxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailtxt);
    retrieveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieveBtn);
    retrieveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fetchData();
        }
    });}


private void fetchData() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/demo/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
   Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

    Call<List<Details_Pojo>> call = api.getstatus();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Details_Pojo>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Details_Pojo>> call, Response<List<Details_Pojo>> response) {


            List<Details_Pojo> adslist = response.body();

            String name = adslist.get(0).getName();
            String age = adslist.get(0).getAge();
            String phone = adslist.get(0).getPhone();
            String email = adslist.get(0).getEmail();

            nametxt.setText(name);
            agetxt.setText(age);
            phonetxt.setText(phone);
            emailtxt.setText(email);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Details_Pojo>> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+t.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}}
```

I've created API.java interface file

public interface Api {

```
String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/demo/";
 @GET("fetch_data.php")
Call<List<Details_Pojo>> getstatus();
```

}

Comment: You want to retrieve data from a REST Api with your application ? You should look into tools like retrofit.

Comment: I added retrofit library but I'm getting this error 
"Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $"

Comment: It looks like the `gson` object is not used. To use it to parse incoming JSON data, use `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))`. However, it appears that the data you receive does not match valid JSON syntax, and this will not be fixed by using this`Gson` object. Either you fix the server's response, or you handle the received data differently.

Answer (score 0):

Check your base URL
.baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/demo/") and change it to .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2/demo/")